# SharpDX XAudio2 no Sound with effects parameters

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, sharpdx, xaudio2

I am working on an application in C# using XAudio2 from SharpDX. I know its outdated but instead of CSCore it offers the better Reverb. The aim itself is simple: load a wav file (48khz,24bit,1channel), get it through the XAudio2 Reverb with several Reverb presets and do a playback.

I managed to implement everything for a normal playback and also built in the Reverb. The audio file will be played back with the defaul reverb settings but as soon as I change the preset or change a specific value (RoomFilterFreq) the file isnt audible anymore and i don´t know why this happens. Does anyone has a clue about this? I worked through the few examples which are still online but could not find a reason for this behaviour.

I´m coding under Visual Studio 2019 with Net 4.7.2. The code looks as followed:

```
xaudio2 = new XAudio2();
xaudio2.StartEngine();
var masteringVoice = new MasteringVoice(xaudio2, 1, 48000);

var stream = new SoundStream(File.OpenRead(soundFilepath));
SharpDX.Multimedia.WaveFormat waveFormat = stream.Format;
var buffer = new AudioBuffer
{
    Stream = stream.ToDataStream(),
    AudioBytes = (int)stream.Length,
    Flags = BufferFlags.EndOfStream
};
stream.Close();
sourceVoice = new SourceVoice(xaudio2, waveFormat, true);

// Set Loop
if (f1.loopcheckBox.Checked == true)
{
    buffer.LoopBegin = buffer.PlayBegin;
    buffer.LoopLength = buffer.PlayLength;
    buffer.LoopCount = AudioBuffer.LoopInfinite;
}
// Set Reverb
if (f1.reverbenableButton.BackColor == Color.LightGreen)
{
    var reverb = new Reverb(xaudio2);
    var reverbparameters = (ReverbParameters)ReverbI3DL2Parameters.Presets.Room;
    var effectDescriptor = new EffectDescriptor(reverb);
    if (waveFormat.Channels == 1)
    {
        effectDescriptor.OutputChannelCount = 1;
    }
    else if (waveFormat.Channels == 2)
    {
        effectDescriptor.OutputChannelCount = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Channelrate not supported!");
        return sourceVoice = null;
    }

    sourceVoice.SetEffectChain(effectDescriptor);
    sourceVoice.SetEffectParameters(0, reverbparameters);
    sourceVoice.EnableEffect(0);

}

sourceVoice.SubmitSourceBuffer(buffer, stream.DecodedPacketsInfo);
sourceVoice.Start();
```

Comment: Does noone has a clue about it? This is so frustrating as  seems to happen whenever a frequencydependent value needs to be changed. The equalizer sections also doesnt spit out any sound when setting parameters but sound passes through when just initiating and enabling

Comment: I can't speak to the C# implementation, but you can find reverb being used in [XAudio2 C++ 3D sound sample](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2/XAudio2Sound3D). You probably want to create a submix voice to attach the reverb to rather than putting it on the source voice.

Comment: Hi Chuck, thanks for your reply which lead me to try xaudio2 with c++. The reverb there works without any issues as well as the parameter changes. Seems to be an issue with SharpDX

Comment: Hi @MrCoffeeeeee I'm having the same issue. The problem that SharpDX has seems to be in the alignment and packing of the structure to pass the reverb parameters. In the working C++ example the size of the structure is 57 bytes while in SharpDX is 60 bytes. Have you found an alternative for C#?